# Converting dotted IP to integer using htonl(inet_addr(IP_str)) return negative values for IP Adresses of Class B and C

Tags: c, linux, htonl

I am trying to convert dotted IP to integer using `htonl(inet_addr(IP_str))`.

The problem is the function returns negative results for IP address of class B and C.

here is some of my code (simplified):

```
int main() {
const char IP1[] = "10.0.0.0";  //Class A
const char IP2[] = "20.0.0.0";  //Class A    
const char IP3[] = "126.0.0.0";  //Class A
const char IP4[] = "128.0.0.0";  //Class B
const char IP5[] = "160.0.0.0";  //Class B
const char IP6[] = "190.0.0.0";  //Class B
const char IP7[] = "193.0.0.0";  //Class C
const char IP8[] = "200.0.0.0";  //Class C

uint32_t integer_ip;
integer_ip = htonl(inet_addr(IP1));
printf("IP1: %s ------> Integer: %d\n",IP1,integer_ip);
integer_ip = htonl(inet_addr(IP2));
printf("IP2: %s ------> Integer: %d\n",IP2,integer_ip);
integer_ip = htonl(inet_addr(IP3));
printf("IP3: %s ------> Integer: %d\n",IP3,integer_ip);   
integer_ip = htonl(inet_addr(IP4));
printf("IP4: %s ------> Integer: %d\n",IP4,integer_ip);
integer_ip = htonl(inet_addr(IP5));
printf("IP5: %s ------> Integer: %d\n",IP5,integer_ip);
integer_ip = htonl(inet_addr(IP6));
printf("IP6: %s ------> Integer: %d\n",IP6,integer_ip);
integer_ip = htonl(inet_addr(IP7));
printf("IP7: %s ------> Integer: %d\n",IP7,integer_ip);
integer_ip = htonl(inet_addr(IP8));
printf("IP8: %s ------> Integer: %d\n",IP8,integer_ip);
return 0;
}
```

and The resuls:

```
IP1: 10.0.0.0 ------> Integer: 167772160   
IP2: 20.0.0.0 ------> Integer: 335544320
IP3: 126.0.0.0 ------> Integer: 2113929216
IP4: 128.0.0.0 ------> Integer: -2147483648
IP5: 160.0.0.0 ------> Integer: -1610612736
IP6: 190.0.0.0 ------> Integer: -1107296256
IP7: 193.0.0.0 ------> Integer: -1056964608
IP8: 200.0.0.0 ------> Integer: -939524096
```

I tested The results on some online tools like [this](http://www.silisoftware.com/tools/ipconverter.php?convert_from=-1610612736) one.

Consider this line of output :

```
IP5: 160.0.0.0 ------> Integer: -1610612736
```

`-1610612736` is equal to `160.0.0.0` whiles `1610612736` is equal to `96.0.0.0.`

The most important requirement for me is speed. 
I don't want to check each IP if it is in class A or not.

How do i resolve this problem?

Thanks?

Comment: Don't print the `uint32_t` as an signed integer then.

Comment: _"because you can use the function in your C++ code"_ That's not a valid reason to use the [tag:c++] tag for your question.

Comment: Whoever told you about "class A, B, C" networks has knowledge so out of date that it's older than most of his students (many assumptions here, but they are probably right). CIDR replaced network classes 24 years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code invokes undefined behaviour for printing an unsigned integer as a signed.

To print the `stdint.h` types, see `inttypes.h`. Use the `PRIu32` macro to print a `uint32_t`:

```
uint32_t u = 42;
printf("Value: %" PRIu32 "\n", u);
```

The standard `%u` conversion type specificer is not guaranteed to be correct, if `uint32_t` is not `typedef unsigned int uint32_t;`. For example with 32 bit `long` and `int`, it could be `typedef`ed to `unsigned` of either.

For hex, use `PRIx32` or `PRIX32`.

### Details:

The Macros map to a string literal with the conversion specifier appropriate for your platform, which can be `"u"`. Notice the `%` must be given in the peceeding part. The standard C feature of concatenating adjscent string literals will generate the final format-string. There will be no run-time overhead.

Comment: Yes, The standard %u conversion type specificer is not guaranteed to be correct!

Comment: You're missing the `%` before the type specifier.

Comment: @dbush: Yes, thanks. They indeed just provide the conversion type, so you can add format-modificators, field-width, etc. like for the normal specifiers.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing wrong is your format strings. Since those are unsigned numbers, you should be using `%u` instead of `%d`, assuming `uint32_t` maps to `unsigned int` on your compiler (which it probably does unless you're targeting an 8 or 16 bit processor).

If you want to ensure that your code is portable to systems where the `int` type is not 32 bits wide, you'll need to use the `PRIu32` macro (or another `PRI*32` macro, such as `PRIx32` for hexadecimal) [defined in `inttypes.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/inttypes.h.html)

You use the macro in place of the format specifier like this:

```
printf("IP1: %s ------> Integer: %" PRIu32 "\n",IP1,integer_ip);
```

Comment: There is no guarantee `%u` or `%x` are correct either.

Comment: The majority of systems does **not** have 32 bit `int`s!

Comment: @Olaf That is a dangerous claim and largely impossible to prove.

Comment: @tofro: Not really. Just have a look at the market-shares of 8 and 16 bit MCUs and DSPs. x86 is some decades below that. Even ARM Cortex-M has still not reached this level (other CPU architectures were never relevant here). Check your car: you most likely have more than 10 8/16 bit MCUs, but only few 32 bitters, if any.

Comment: So you only drive oldtimers? Any car since the 1980ies has MCUs inside. Whatever reason that might be: it is nonsense. Let that apart: you know what the word "example" means?

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for corrections. I've added a recommendation to use the portable solution.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, the `%d` format specifier is for printing a signed `int`.  The value you are passing is unsigned.  Using the wrong format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to use the `%u` format specifier to print the values as unsigned.

Better yet, use the `%x` format specifier instead to print the values as unsigned hexadecimal.  That way, every pair of hex characters corresponds to a byte of the IP address, making it easier to read.

EDIT:

The C standard however doesn't guarantee that an `int` is at least 32 bits.  You need to use the `PRIu32` or `PRIx32` macros to get the proper format specifier for a `uint32_t`:

```
printf("%" PRIx32 "\n", integer_ip);
```

Comment: There is no guarantee `%u` or `%x` are correct either.

Comment: @Olaf  Added reference to `PRIx32`

Answer (score 1):

`htonl` returns a 32-bit **unsigned** integer.

The format specifier `%d` you use to print the values is intended for **signed** integer values.

Use a format specifier that fits the data type (`%u`) and the values will be displayed as positive unsigned numbers.

Comment: There is no guarantee `%u` or `%x` are correct either.

Comment: There is a big chance that %u (or %x) is much more correct than %d. And, as the question is tagged Linux, there is a very high chance of being correct on non-exotic Linuxes

Comment: There is no guarantee `uint32_t` is an `unsigned int`. could be `unsigned long` as well on 32 bit Linux. While they would have the same representation, it still was UB according to the standard. Why not use the correct way? Feel free to state the problem the correct way would not solve.